# Outdoor Gang Box Replacement

Tags: electrical

Newbie 1st posting here so apologies in advance for any posting faux pas.

I have a one GFCI outlet installed in a plastic gang box that was installed for a water feature approx. 4 years ago. The gang box is failing I fear. Whenever there is a heavy rainfall, the GFCI is tripped. Once the weather gets better, I am able to reset the GFCI.

I would like to replace the GFCI and the box. I was wondering if I could install the GFCI in a "Ticonn" waterproof Electrical Junction Box IP67 instead of a big box retailer's weatherproof metal gang box?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fdyvy.jpg)

Comment: On my phone, so I couldn’t go digging, but I doubt the linked box is UL listed. Sometimes doing the most normal thing (big box waterproof metal enclosure with low-profile in-use cover) is the best.

Comment: Gotta pic of your actual installed box?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, replace the box with something that is more weather-resistant, with an in-use cover. But don't stick a GFCI/receptacle in the box. Instead, put the GFCI somewhere *inside your house*. That can be:

- GFCI/breaker - most expensive
- GFCI/deadfront (i.e., "just" a GFCI, though it can usually also be used as a switch) - this is a bit more than just a GFCI/receptacle because while the device is not expensive you need to add a box somewhere to put it
- GFCI/receptacle - least expensive, at least it is if you have an existing receptacle that you can simply replace that is earlier in the circuit.

With any of these, you can provide protection to the outside receptacle while keeping the GFCI electronics inside. That won't stop all GFCI trips, but it will help the GFCI last longer and it may cut down some on the GFCI trips, depending on the nature of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

That box doesn't show a UL listing.

Also it is just a box. No mounting for an outlet. You would have to still have a box to mount the GFCI, and then mount that box inside the Ticonn box.

A better alternative may be [this poly carb. box](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0C5VKSZVR)  and UL listed [Cover](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B092C62N3B)

No drilling. The box and cover are made to work together and have a standard or GFCI outlet mounted inside.